# Websphere server with liferay developer studio

Tags: java, liferay, websphere, websphere-8, liferay-ide

I have to develop a program running on websphere server on liferay developer studio. On "Define a New server" screen, Liferay developer studio suggests me to choose a Websphere Server as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oafRu.jpg).

But on the [next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4guT.jpg) screen ("Websphere runtime for Liferay V.6.0 EE"), in the Liferay runtime stub part Liferay developer studio don't suggest me a websphere runtime stub type.

And where I can find the Liferay runtime stub directory?

Comment: Incidentally, *someone* has just asked a very similar question here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/56481447 . Maybe that solves your problem?

Comment: It was me. Thank you :) !